# create connection using user password and dsn cx_oracle having multiple host

Tags: python, oracle

I need to run an external .sql file using python.I have found a way to do it but it requires connection string as an argument my connection consists of two hosts

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
import cx_Oracle

path='D:\Release\CR01234\Ver 1.0.0.0\DBScripts\updatencsusr.sql'

NDB = """
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =172.38.7.113)(PORT = 1515))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =172.38.7.114)(PORT = 1515))
(CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVICE_NAME = qsssdb)
    )
)
"""
#------DB Connection Details-------
User='abcd'
Password='abcd#123'


try :
     connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user=User,password=Password,dsn=NDB,encoding="UTF-8")
     cursor = connection.cursor()
except Exception  as e :
    logging.exception("CollateralValidation:Utility-> Connection to DB Failed : |")  



def run_sql_script(connstr, filename):
    try:
        print(filename)
        sqlplus = Popen(['sqlplus','-S', connstr], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,encoding='utf8')
        sqlplus.stdin.write('@'+filename)
        return sqlplus.communicate()
    except exception as e :
        print(e)


run_sql_script(dsn,path)
```

it is giving error as below

```
    ('SP2-0306: Invalid option.\nUsage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM}] [edition=value]]\nwhere <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]\n      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]\n', '')
```

I am not sure how to make connection string for multiple host in dsn?

Comment: The error message from sqlplus  is telling that the params are wrong, and that's because you are passing the dsn (i.e. what you have in NDB) to sqlplus, without the username/pwd part. And why are you doing this like that? I mean using python to call sqlplus?

Comment: @gsalem I will have mutliple .sql files so instead of reading it I wanted it all to directly get  executed because queries my be complexed in .sql .that's why .and I know I am paasing dsn which is wrong how can I pass connection string using dsn,user and password.

Comment: I can't recommend calling out to SQL*Plus.  Instead either (i) move all the SQL statements into Python, (ii) or use code like https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/8.3.0/samples/sample_env.py#L118-L151 (which assumes statements end in a `/` not a semi-colon).